# Capybara/Poltergeist: Check that div has children

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, capybara, poltergeist

I need a way to check if an element has children.

```
    <div class="purchaseRoMPixels">
       <img style="display:none" src="//api.com;value=20">
       <noscript>&lt;img height="1" width="1" alt="" style="display:none" src="https://www.facebook.com" /&gt;</noscript>
    </div>
```

I tried the following but they dont work

```
find(".purchaseRomPixels").children.length.should > 0
```

This also does not correctly test what I am trying to test

```
find(".purchaseRoMPixels").text.should == ""
```

It will always return true, because there is no text in that div. But I want it to return true only if those elements exist in the div.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
expect(find(:css, '.purchaseRoMPixels').text).to_not be_empty
```

I think you messed up in this line of your examples:

```
find(".purchaseRoMPixels").text.should == ""
```

and wanted to use a not equals rather than an equals operator, I mean:

```
find(".purchaseRoMPixels").text.should != ""
```